# MYSQL Query JOIN multiple fields to one field

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I've tried searching around for an answer, but haven't found one that seems to quite get me in the place I'm looking to be.  I've got two tables right now I'm trying to join.

adhesive_table

```
id | adhesive_name | adhesive_code
1  | Ivory         | 0090
2  | Jet Black     | 0100
3  | Khaki         | 0110
4  | Natural       | 0120
```

and a match_table

```
id | brand_id | sheet_name | match_1 | match_2
1  | 1        | Wheat      | 0110    | 0120
2  | 1        | Dew        | 0090    | 0110
```

Etc...  There are thousands of matches and hundreds of adhesives.  I'm trying to grab the match and return the corresponding adhesive_name using a JOIN.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM match_table
JOIN adhesive_table
ON match_table.match_1 = adhesive_table.adhesive_code
WHERE match_table.brand_id
IN ($b)";
```

(the $b is sent through a $.post and corresponds to the brand_id) 
 
And that works fine for a single match.  But for many there is a second (alternative) match available indicated by match_2.  So I've been trying to get a JOIN working where I can grab the names for match 1,2,3 to no avail.  I've been trying queries like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM match_table
LEFT JOIN adhesive_table
ON match_table.match_1 = adhesive_table.adhesive_code
LEFT JOIN adhesive_table
ON match_table.match_2 = adhesive_table.adhesive_code
WHERE match_table.brand_id
IN ($b)";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM match_table
JOIN adhesive_table
ON match_table.match_1 = adhesive_table.adhesive_code
AND match_table.match_2 = adhesive_table.adhesive_code
WHERE match_table.brand_id
IN ($b)";
```

But neither work.  I'm wondering if the formatting of my tables prevents this from working, or if I'm missing something obvious.  Is this somewhere that group_concat needs to be used?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

I should add the table I'm hoping to get as a result would be as follows:

```
brand_id = 1
sheet_name = Wheat
 match_1 = (adhesive_code & adhesive_name) 0110 Khaki
 match_2 = (adhesive_code & adhesive_name) 0120 Natural
```

After the query the results are put into an array

```
$arr = array();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $arr[] = $row;
} 
} else {
$arr[] = "";
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This is sent back to my main file, and I'm getting the results in a loop that looks like:

```
$.post("getmatches.php",{checkedBrand:checkedBrand},function(json){
    for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
        htmlFormat += 
        " sheet : " + json[i].sheet_name
        + " - " + "match_1 : " + json[i].adc1 
        + " - " + "name : "  + json[i].ad1
        + " - " + "match_2 : " + json[i].adc2
        + " - " + "name : "  + json[i].ad2
        + "<br />";
    } // end for loop
    $(".stuffs").html(htmlFormat)
}) // end post
```

Much thanks for Sebas' patience and help, the final working method used is as follows.  I added selecting the columns AS alias so I could reference them in the javascript after the json return.

```
$sql="
SELECT brand_id, sheet_name, a.adhesive_name AS ad1, a.adhesive_code AS adc1, b.adhesive_name ad2, b.adhesive_code adc2
FROM match_table
LEFT JOIN adhesive_table a ON match_table.match_1 = a.adhesive_code
LEFT JOIN adhesive_table b ON match_table.match_2 = b.adhesive_code
WHERE
match_table.brand_id IN ($b)";
```

Comment: Please, don't use `&nbsp;` to format your code, but use the ` instead or indent it (see my edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT id, brand_id, sheet_name, a.adhesive_name, a.adhesive_code FROM match_table 
INNER JOIN adhesive_table a
ON match_table.match_1 = a.adhesive_code
WHERE match_table.brand_id
IN ($b)
UNION
SELECT id, brand_id, sheet_name, a.adhesive_name, a.adhesive_code FROM match_table 
INNER JOIN adhesive_table a 
ON match_table.match_2 = a.adhesive_code
WHERE match_table.brand_id
IN ($b)";
```

EDIT: I edited my above query to show both matchs in separate lines more clearly. On the other hand, if you want them both in the same line, here is another different one:

```
$sql="
SELECT id, brand_id, sheet_name, a.adhesive_name, a.adhesive_code, b.adhesive_name, b.adhesive_code 
FROM match_table 
    LEFT JOIN adhesive_table a ON match_table.match_1 = a.adhesive_code
    LEFT JOIN adhesive_table b ON match_table.match_2 = b.adhesive_code
WHERE 
    match_table.brand_id IN ($b)
AND (a.id IS NOT NULL OR b.id IS NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: Yes!  This.  Thank you very much that is amazing.  UNION.  Still newish to MYSQL, didn't realise that was what I was after.  You're a star.

Comment: Is there any way to merge the contents into a single row?  Using UNION it seems to duplicate everything.  I'm returning the results through AJAX, and running a forloop so I get double data.  Is this somewhere I should use AS?  

example:  http://integra.pyknyk.ca/w3c/checkbox.php

If you click on solid surface > westag-getalit (it's a small chart so easy to manage)

You can see the data comes back twice.  You get match 1 name then match 2 (null which is fine if there is no data) name (repeats the name for match 1)

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to replace the left joins by inner joins ;) see the edited code.

Comment: What do you mean closer? Is there anything missing?

Comment: That I can't differentiate between the adhesive name for match_1 and the name for match_2, it echoes it out twice.  I get a result like:
match_1 0080 Ebony, match_2 0290 Ebony (when 0290 shouldn't be ebony)
then the second time I get match_1 0080 White Linen, match_2 0290 White Linen.  I don't want to trouble you further.  This is super close, I'm just trying to see if throwing an alias in there somewhere is what I need.

Comment: could you please identify the data type of columns match1, match2 and adhesive_code?

Comment: All three are VARCHAR.  The product SKU's require many colours to start with 00, or 0.  So I couldn't use number/int.  Did you see the url I posted in the previous comments?

Comment: I understand, match1 and match2 might refer to the same thing but with different reference numbers that's why you want to skip doubles. So for example now I see: match_1 : 0260 - name : Ebony - match_2 : 0080 - name : Ebony. This is a concatenation you are doing yourself... Could you post the loop please?

Comment: Added it to the post.  I know that I'm calling adhesive_name twice, I just can't figure out how to separate the values, so I thought that the query should be altered to break it up before sending it back to the javascript.

Comment: I edited my query and added another one so you can chose to display separate rows for each match or both of them in the same row.

Comment: Yup.  You're amazing.  The query is working like a charm.  I just need to figure out how to format it in javascript, but this was a real life saver.  Thanks for all the time you've spent helping me.  The second one is exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Your first try was fine except for a single detail: if you join on the same table twice, use aliases:

```
SELECT * FROM match_table
LEFT JOIN adhesive_table ad1 ON match_table.match_1 = ad1.adhesive_code
LEFT JOIN adhesive_table ad2 ON match_table.match_2 = ad2.adhesive_code
WHERE match_table.brand_id=1;
```

Comment: I keep getting undefined with this, but I see the logic.  I'll keep playing around to see if I can get it working.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah this query works with the first LEFT JOIN... but the second one causes it to return nothing.  Or vice versa, if I keep the second and remove the first.  Regardless only one seems to be accepted.